# Terraform Error with GCP for compute.networks.create

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

I'm running through this [GCP GitHub TerraForm tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/docs/terraform/get-started-with-terraform)

```
Terraform Apply is failing in GCP Build with this error
Error: Error creating Network: googleapi: Error 403: Required 'compute.networks.create' permission for '', forbidden
```

The service accont I am using has the right permissions via custom role

```
compute.networks.create
```

I have tried this solution previously and added four base roles
https://github.com/gruntwork-io/terraform-google-gke/issues/53

It seems that it should not be failing since the permission exists but GCP says it does not

Answer (score 2):

I met the same issue when I changed my google account and project, at last found the solution, it works for me.

please use `gcloud auth application-default login` instead of `gcloud auth login` to login and do authorization.